# Type checks in Typescript with Zod

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

I have the code:

```
import { z } from "zod";

interface f {
   tmp: number;
}
```

How can I now check that object like `{ tmp: 123 }` has same structure as `f`?

Comment: Create an object schema? https://zod.dev/?id=basic-usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Zod` to create a schema for your interface `f` and then use the parse method to check if an object adheres to that schema.

```
import { z, ZodError } from "zod";

interface f {
 tmp: number;
}

const schema = z.object({
 tmp: z.number()
});

const myObject = { tmp: 123 };

try {
 const validatedObject: f = schema.parse(myObject);
 console.log("Object is valid:", validatedObject);
} catch (error) {
 if (error instanceof ZodError) {
  console.error("Object is not valid:", error.errors);
 } else {
  throw error;
 }
}
```

So in this example, `schema.parse(myObject)` will throw a ZodError if `myObject` doesn't match the structure defined by the `f` interface. If the object is valid, it will be assigned to `validatedObject`.

---

**Update**:

The `z.object` method allows you to dynamically create a schema  based on the structure of the `f` interface.

```
import { z, ZodError } from "zod";
interface f {
  tmp: number;
}
const schema = z.object(
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries<Record<string, z.ZodType<any, any, any>>>({
      tmp: z.number(),
    })
  )
);

const myObject = { tmp: 123 };

try {
  const validatedObject: f = schema.parse(myObject);
  console.log("Object is valid:", validatedObject);
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof ZodError) {
    console.error("Object is not valid:", error.errors);
  } else {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

This way you don't have to manually list all the fields in `z.object`. This code dynamically creates a schema based on the fields defined in the f interface.

Comment: yes, nut what can I do to generate this scheme without declaration of each field of `f` inside `z.object()`?

Comment: Please find my updated answer

Comment: It worked thank you